# C - Reading strings from text file into arrays inside a structure

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I am trying to read text from a .txt file into arrays of a structure.
This is my code (I have played around with this a heap so apologies if it seems all over the place):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int j = 0;

    char temp[4];

    struct userStruct {             // a struct definition for the users;
        char pin[5];
        char first[26];
        char last[26];
    };
    struct userStruct userList[10];     // an array of struct user to hold 10 users
    struct userStruct * users;
    users = &userList;

    FILE * filePtr;

    filePtr = fopen ("users.txt", "r");
    if (filePtr != NULL)
    {
        fscanf(filePtr, "%s %s %s %s", users[i].pin[j], users[i].first[j], users[i].last[j], temp);
        if (strcmp(temp, "\n"))
        {
            i++;
            j++;

        }
        printf("PIN %s| First %s| Last %s|", users[i].pin[j], users[i].first[j], users[i].last[j]);

        fclose(filePtr);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Unable to open users.txt");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The users.txt file contains the text:

```
1234 John Smith
5678 Barry Cool
```

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: `users = &userList;` --> `users = userList;`

Comment: and what is the question / problem?

Comment: `Unable to open users.txt` is not a useful error message.  Try `perror("users.txt");`

Comment: Each line of input has 3 values.  Why does the scanf format string have 4 conversions?

Comment: Note that the `scanf` format `%s` will never include any kind of space (including newline). It will, on the other hand, read and *ignore* (throw away) leading space.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications @WilliamPursell
SouravGhosh - the question is what part of the code is causing the input not to be stored into the struct correctly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want 3 conversion specifiers in the scanf.  Try

```
if( 3 == fscanf(filePtr, "%4s %25s %25s", users[i].pin, users[i].first, users[i].last) ){ ...
```

The printf is also weird.  Try:

```
printf("PIN %s| First %s| Last %s|", users[i].pin, users[i].first, users[i].last);
```

Comment: I implemented these changes, the output I get is correct for the first line.
When I try to output the second line ```5678 Barry Cool```, it does not seem to be stored in the userList struct?

It prints out ```PIN □#□☺| First | Last  ↑♣|```

Comment: @BlackSolis In the code you show, you only read the first line, so the 2nd entry of the array remains uninitialized.  It's tough to answer the question without knowing what code you actually use, but my guess is you didn't implement the loop and never read the second line.

Comment: Thanks @William Pursell - you are correct, I extracted this from the main code to trouble shoot and I left the loop behind.... Many thanks sir.